# For regression model, why the validation set passed to model.fit have different metric result than the model.evaluate?

Tags: keras

I have a regression model with `Euclidean` distance as a loss function and `RMSE` as a metric evaluation (lower is better). When I passed my train, test sets to `model.fit` I have `train_rmse`, and  `test_rmse` which their values made sense to me. But when I pass the test sets into `model.evalute` after loading the weight of the trained model I got different results which are approximately twice the result with `model.fit`. And I am aware of the difference that should happen between the train evaluation and test evaluation as I know from Keras that :

> the training loss is the average of the losses over each batch of training data. Because your model is changing over time, the loss over the first batches of an epoch is generally higher than over the last batches. On the other hand, the testing loss for an epoch is computed using the model as it is at the end of the epoch, resulting in a lower loss.

But here I am talking about the result of test-set passed to model.fit in which I beleived is evaluated on the final model. In Keras documentation, they said on validation argument that I am passing the test set in it:

> validation_data: Data on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch. The model will not be trained on this data.

When I searched about the problem I found several issues

1- Some people like [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977) report that this issue is with the model itself if they have batch normalization layer,or if you do transfer learning and freeze some BN layers like [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9965#issuecomment-382857348).  my model has BN layers, and I did not freeze any layer.  Also,  I used the same model for the mulit-class classification problem (not regression) and the result was the same for test set in the `model.fit` and `model.evaluate`.

2- Other people like said that this is related with either the prediction or metric calculation like [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5140), in which they found that this difference is related with the different of dtype for y_true and y_pred if someone is float32 and other float64 for example, then the metric calculation will be different.  When they unified the dtype the problem is fixed.

I believed that the last case applied to me since in the regression task my labels now is tf.float32. My y_true labels already cast to `tf.float32` through `tfrecord`, so I tried to cast the y_pred to `tf.float32` before the `rmse` calculation, and I still have the difference in the result.

So My questions are:

1. Why this difference in results
2. To whom I should rely for test set, on `model.fit` result or `model.evalute`
3. I know that for training loss and accuracy, keras does a running average over the batches, and I know for model.evalute, these metric are calculated by taking all the dataset one time on the final model. But how the validation loss and accuracy calculated for validation set passed to model.fit?

**UPDATE:** 
The problem was in the shape conflict between the `y_true` and `y_pred`. As for y_true label I save it in `tfrecords` as float single value and eventually will be with the size of `[batch_size]` while the regression model gives the prediction as `[batch_size, 1]` and then the result of `tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)` in `rmse` equation will result in matrix of `[batch_size, batch_sizze]` and with taking the mean of this final one you will never guess it is wrong and the code will not throw any error but the calculation of `rmse` will be wrong. I am still working to make the shape consistent but still didn't find a good solution.